# Drawing parallel coordinates for random selection of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I have 500 samples (rows) in my data which is stored as a csv file. You can see 5 rows of it as follow:

```
path,Ktype,label,CGX,CGY,C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4,total1,total2,totalI3,total4,feature1,feature2,feature3,feature4,feature5,feature6,feature7,feature8,feature9,feature10,feature11,feature12,A,B,C,D,feature13,feature14,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    .\Mydata\Case1,k1,1,42,33,0,57.44534,0,52597,71,16,10,276,4038,3789.631,0.6173469,0.6499337,2.103316,0.6661285,1.065539,248.3694,0.630161,0.000192848,0.9999996,0.000642777,1,0,0,1,9.60E-05,3136.698,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    .\Mydata\Case2,k1,2,163,29,0,43.28862,0,49050,71,16,10,248,2944,2587.956,0.5726808,0.5681185,2.130387,0.601512,1.137578,356.0444,0.6335613,0.000327267,1.000029,0.001271235,1,0,0,1,0.00010854,2676.418,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    .\Mydata\Case3,k1,3,774,19,0,45.26291,0,53455,71,16,10,212,2366,1982.547,0.408179,0.4579566,1.994296,0.6615351,1.193415,383.4534,0.7153812,0.000264522,1.000031,0.001210507,1,1,0,0,9.54E-05,3221.289,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    .\Mydata\Case4,k1,4,1116,25,0,80.76469,0,57542,71,16,10,284,3908,3453.988,0.3549117,0.4811547,1.982244,0.6088744,1.131446,454.0122,0.6166388,0.000314288,0.9999836,0.00129846,0,1,1,0,0.000140592,2143.42,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    .\Mydata\Case5,k1,5,1364,59,1,52.96776,0,49670,71,16,10,228,2725,2642.675,0.4328255,0.475517,1.859871,0.6587288,1.031152,82.32471,0.5775694,0.000466264,0.9999803,0.001765345,0,1,1,0,0.00012014,2439.636,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I am drawing parallel coordinates for my data. This is the part of code which reads in the csv file and filters it:

```
d3.csv("Mydata.csv", function(raw_data) {

  // Convert quantitative scales to floats
  data = raw_data.map(function(d) {
    for (var k in d) {
      if (!_.isNaN(raw_data[0][k] - 0) && k != 'id' && k != 'cgX' && k != 'cgY') {
        d[k] = parseFloat(d[k]) || 0;
      }
    };
    return d;
  });

  // Extract the list of numerical dimensions and create a scale for each.
  xscale.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(k) {
    return (_.isNumber(data[0][k])) && (yscale[k] = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[k]; }))
      .range([h, 0]));
  }));


  // And the rest of the code for drawing parallel coordinates.
  // It is similar to the code in this link:
  //                http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3150059

}
```

Now, I want to change it in a way that instead of drawing 500 samples (500 polylines in parallel coordinates), it selects 100 of data randomly. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Do it in 2 passes.

First read in all the data...

```
d3.csv("Mydata.csv", function(raw_data) {...}
```

Then pick 100 at random and feed it to rendering function.

The bonus is that you don't have parse / transform the coords you don't want to render.
Also if you hit 100 before the full 500 is read, you can simply exit early and jump to the rendering algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I select 100 at random? Would you please give me more details?